# Any way to call $q notify without causing $digest cycle?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-digest

I have an app that $digest cycle takes about 5ms, and I am using `$q.defer` with `deferred.notify` a lot inside my app. The issue is that every time `deferred.notify` is called, a digest cycle will be scheduled, and cause angular running it for 5ms.

As a result, when I fetching few thousands rows of data from server (through WebSocket, the data are received one by one), the app can use 100% CPU and become very unresponsive. The only thing I do with those data is save them into IndexedDB.

Is any way to use `$q` and `notify` without schedule a $digest cycle?

I am thinking using a different promise implementation for WebSocket and IndexedDB related code, but I don't like the idea to have two promise implementations and it is almost impossible to know which kind of promise will be returned after a long chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a different promise implementation, or really that sounds a lot like a job for [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS). A non-angular promise like the browser-native version or Bluebird wouldn't trigger digest cycles on all notifies. Then you'd just have to manually digest stuff - this is what I do: I use RxJS to process websocket events and manually call scope.$apply on appropriate scopes occasionally when needed (as you - I don't need to update my scopes on every websocket event).

Comment: RxJS sounds good. That should solve my concern about two different kind of promises.

Answer (score 1):

I just found [$$q](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/0ba14e1853e1d40a14570a74d1c82a222bd3be15/src/ng/q.js#L256). From what I understand, it is $q without digest cycle which is exactly what I want.

However it is an undocumented private service.